# "list index out of range" in discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wanted to make a discord bot predictor for my server, which i managed to do, but after a few uses and then leaving the bot not in use after typing a new command the bot says incorrect round ID, but if restart the code on visual code studio the bot works again. the command is /towers. here is the code

````
import discord
from discord import app_commands 
from random import randint
import time


class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents = discord.Intents.all())
        self.synced = False 

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced: 
            await tree.sync()
            self.synced = True
        print(f"We have logged in as {self.user}.")

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = 'towers', description='towers gamemode')
async def towers(interaction: discord.Interaction, round_id:str, tile_amount:int):
    if len(round_id) == 8:
        start_time = time.time()
        grid = [['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓'],['❓','❓','❓']]

        count = 0
        while count < tile_amount:
            a = randint(0,2)
            grid[count][a] = '✅'
            count += 1

        chance = randint(45,95)
        if tile_amount < 4:
                chance = chance - 15

        em = discord.Embed(color=0x0025ff)
        em.add_field(name="Grid", value="```"+grid[7][0]+grid[7][1]+grid[7][2]+"\n"+grid[6][0]+grid[6][1]+grid[6][2]+"\n"+grid[5][0]+grid[5][1]+grid[5][2]+"\n"+grid[4][0]+grid[4][1]+grid[4][2] +"\n"+ \
            grid[3][0]+grid[3][1]+grid[3][2] + "\n" + grid[2][0]+grid[2][1]+grid[2][2] + "\n" + grid[1][0]+grid[1][1]+grid[1][2] + "\n" + grid[0][0]+grid[0][1]+grid[0][2] + "```" \
                + f"**Accuracy**\n```{chance}%```\n**Round ID**\n```{round_id}```\n**Response Time:**\n```{str(int(time.time() - int(start_time)))}```")
        
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)
    else:
        em = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
        em.add_field(name='Error', value="Invalid round id")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=em)


client.run('')
````

This is what is says in visual code studio, i have no clue on how to fix it.

```
We have logged in as Towers Predictor#0000.
2023-04-21 00:07:29 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'towers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\61416\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commapy", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\61416\OneDrive\Desktop\Predictor\Predictor.py", line 31, in towers
    grid[count][a] = '✅'
    ~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\61416\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree. line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commapy", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commadiscord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'towers' raised an exception: IndexError: list indet of range
```

Comment: What commands did you run?

Comment: the bot is only supposed to run the command /towers which shows Round ID and tile number

Comment: Ok, but what command exactly did you run the server?

Comment: the exact command i did was  /towers

Comment: Did you pass any parameters? Did discord ask you for any parameters to that command?

Comment: What is the value of `tile_amount`?

Comment: Aside: don't use a `while` loop. `for count in range(tile_amount):` is more pythonic.

Comment: The problem is that `tile_amount` is more than `len(grid)`.

Comment: `grid[count][a] = '✅'` grid is a list of 8 items, therefore this statement is only legal if `count` is 7 or less.  It must have been more than that.

Comment: no it did not, it just says "incorrect round ID" but like i said when i restart the code on visual studio and put in the exact same round ID it generates a response, whenever the bot says incorrect round ID, it says in visual studio the same stuff above " ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'towers' " etc. and doesnt work until i restart the code. i just wanna know if somewhere in the code needs fixing

Comment: @ john Gordon, yes it was 32 but the round ID consists of 8 so i changed it, which could be why its not working, can anyone confirm that?

Comment: someone answered the post, but its gone ididnt note it down in time